# Iterate over array and delete some entities while not leaving undefined

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I would like to delete specific positions in an array and also reduce the length of the array such that it doesn't contain an undefined position after the delete. I'm also iterating over the array.

I can imagine a brute-force solution which would iterate twice over the array, but I just thought I'd check and see if there's something easier out there.

Here's what I've got:

```
_.each(foo._events, function (eventGroup) {

    var keys = _.keys(eventGroup);

    _.each(keys, function (key) {
        if (eventGroup[key].ctx.isClosed) {
            delete eventGroup[key];
            console.log("Deleting closed");
        }
    });
});
```

This leaves an undefined element in the slot, though.

I was exploring some of the options here: [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array) but I suspect modifying the array's length while iterating over it might result in odd behavior? But maybe it's fine since I'm accessing by key -- even though the keys appear to be "0", "1", "2".

Comment: If you're iterating over an array you shouldn't be using `delete`. That's for removing properties from objects. Is it an object or an array?

Comment: @Andy I am trying to fix something with Backbone.JS, you can see that they use a similar pattern to what I do above here: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood completely, but maybe `filter` is what you're looking for?

```
foo._events = _.filter(foo._events, function (eventGroup) {
    return _.every(_.values(eventGroup), function(v) {
         return !v.ctx.isClosed
    })
})
```

Comment: Georg -- Thanks for your proposed solution. This got me on the right track. Could you please edit your response to this: and I'll accept it? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3d5f7aaf1f102289bfd0 oh whoops -- looks like you beat me to it. OK, accepting

Answer (score 0):

Rather than iterating over the array twice, have you thought about sliding the elements down in one loop?  I.e., once you find the index of the element to delete, assign the value at that index i to the value at index i + 1, so on and so forth.  You're right, changing the size of the array while iterating is dangerous, and in stricter languages is not even allowed.  Once you're done reassigning the elements within the loop, you can change the size to N - 1.